# MySQLI and Select 1

Tags: php, mysql

When getting data from the databas my if statement isn't working as expected, even though I have the $badgename in the database for that user I got "You get a new badge". But it dosen't put it on.

Im new to MySQLI so it's probably something I missed...

```
$numberofposts=$row['posts'];
$userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
$badgename = "Legend";

if($numberofposts >= 10){

$SQL = $mysqli->query("SELECT 1 FROM `badges` WHERE `mid`='$userid' AND 'badge' = '$badgename'");
$num = $SQL->num_rows;

if($num > 0){
 echo "You got a new badge";
 $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO badges ('mid', 'badge') VALUES ('$userid', '$badgename')");
}
else 
{
echo "You already have this badge";
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please read this - http://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php. Injecting values directly into your queries is unsafe

Comment: while in theory it is unsafe, typecasting and proper sanitizitation will prevent the injection in most cases. my opinion is that the op needs to learn this method first and learn the strengths and weaknesses first hand before he will be able to move on to prepared statements and fully understand what they accomplish.

Comment: @r3wt Don't know about you but I find preparing a statement and binding parameters a lot easier (and shorter) than directly sanitising input parameters and interpolating them into the query.

Comment: @Phil you are right, prepared statements are an advantage over queries. i just don't think the op is ready for them yet.

Comment: @r3wt OP could read the article linked, then they'd be ready :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YOu have typo's in both queries:

replace the single quotes( ' ) on `badge` with backticks( ` )
from your select query.

then replace the single quotes with backticks in the insert query. ex:

```
 $numberofposts=$row['posts'];
 $userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
 $badgename = "Legend";

if($numberofposts >= 10){

 $SQL = $mysqli->query("SELECT 1 FROM `badges` WHERE `mid`='$userid' AND `badge` =     '$badgename'");
 $num = $SQL->num_rows;

 if($num > 0){
  echo "You got a new badge";
 $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `badges` (`mid`, `badge`) VALUES ('$userid', '$badgename')");
 }
 else 
{
echo "You already have this badge";
}
```

Comment: That was an easy fix, thanks! The good thing was that everything else was right I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Your INSERT query is wrong.

You have single-quotes around your column names, but you should be using backticks instead (like in the SELECT query)

Comment: `AND 'badge' = '$badgename'`

Comment: Oh yeah. Missed that!